# Why is my static constructor not called per script invocation

Tags: powershell

In Powershell 5 I can define classes, and even static constructors:

```
class Foo
{
    static Foo() 
    {
        write-host 'Initializing Foo Class';
    }
}
```

Problem is: when I create a script foo.ps1 and execute it several times from the powershell command line, the 'Initializing...' line appears only once. I have to modify my source to see it again.

Obviously, Powershell has loaded my script and keeps it loaded until it is recompiled. But that is not what I would expect of an command line script. What is necessary to make Powershell start my script fresh each time?

Comment: That's the whole point of a static constructor - it's only (ie. at most) invoked once per appdomain for the lifetime of the defining type

Comment: I know that, I'm doing C# since 2001. This seems to be weird behaviour for a scripting shell. So you're saying this is by design, that a script is loaded once by the shell until I change the source? Can I circumvent that somehow? I want behaviour like in a C# console app: clean slate for every start. Initializing all class statics at script startup would become a nightmare otherwise.